# How to create a Vertical Dropdown with Menu with Gridview?

Tags: android

I want to know how to develop a custom dropdown icons Menu with GridView options from Menu.

This is my code for custom down icons

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="#c2ec97"
>     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     tools:context="viralandroid.com.androidxmluserinterfacetutorial.MainActivity">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/dropdown_custom_icon_menu"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="#5bace6"
>         android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
>         android:onClick="verticalDropDownIconMenu"
>         android:padding="16dp"
>         android:text="DropDown\t"
>         android:textColor="#eee" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/dropdown_custom_icon_menu"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="Android Custom Vertical Dropdown Menu IconsAndroid Custom Vertical. Break line after Icon in Menu Item
> ```
>
> Android.
>                   Dropdown Menu IconsAndroid Custom Vertical Dropdown. popup menu with icon in android example.
>                   Android Custom Vertical Dropdown Menu Icons. Android Custom Vertical Dropdown Menu Icons" />
>
> ```
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>             android:text="Android Custom Vertical Dropdown Menu Icons" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/vertical_dropdown_icon_menu_items"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/dropdown_custom_icon_menu"
>         android:background="#333"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:padding="3dp"
>         android:visibility="invisible">
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:background="@drawable/onclick_press_color"
>             android:onClick="menuItemClick"
>             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>             android:paddingLeft="26dp"
>             android:paddingRight="26dp"
>             android:paddingTop="5dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send"
>             android:text="Android Vertical Custom DropDown Menu" />
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/onclick_press_color"
>             android:onClick="menuItemClick"
>             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>             android:paddingLeft="26dp"
>             android:paddingRight="26dp"
>             android:paddingTop="5dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_attach"
>             android:text="Android Vertical Custom DropDown Menu" />
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/onclick_press_color"
>             android:onClick="menuItemClick"
>             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>             android:paddingLeft="26dp"
>             android:paddingRight="26dp"
>             android:paddingTop="5dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_mail"
>             android:text="Android Vertical Custom DropDown Menu" />
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/onclick_press_color"
>             android:onClick="menuItemClick"
>             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>             android:paddingLeft="26dp"
>             android:paddingRight="26dp"
>             android:paddingTop="5dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
>             android:text="Android Vertical Custom DropDown Menu" />
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/onclick_press_color"
>             android:onClick="menuItemClick"
>             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>             android:paddingLeft="26dp"
>             android:paddingRight="26dp"
>             android:paddingTop="5dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_attach"
>             android:text="Android Vertical Custom DropDown Menu" />
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/onclick_press_color"
>             android:onClick="menuItemClick"
>             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>             android:paddingLeft="26dp"
>             android:paddingRight="26dp"
>             android:paddingTop="5dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_action_mail"
>             android:text="Android Vertical Custom DropDown Menu" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

This is what i have :
[image]
This is what i want :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the spinner and that will lead to use an adapter and a couple of layouts.
First in your activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then create a new layout under /res/layout folder and just name it anything like custom_spinner_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then in you MainActivity.java  you need to do your code:

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


        String[] carNames={"Chevy","Dodge","Mazda","Honda","BMW","Toyota"};
        int icons[] = {R.drawable.Chevy, R.drawable.Dodge, R.drawable.Mazda, R.drawable.Honda, R.drawable.BMW, R.drawable.Toyota};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSpinner);
            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),icons,carNames);
            spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {
//your code goes here///
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), carNames[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // something happens here
        }
    }
```

You will need to create a new java class file and name it  CustomAdapter.java and thats gonna be extended fro BaseAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int icons[];
    String[] carNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] icons, String[] carNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.icons = icons;
        this.carNames = carNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_layout, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(icons[i]);
        names.setText(carNames[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

you can get the working code in :
https://github.com/edgebasis/spinnerExample